# Python How to convert the numpy array(dtype=uint16) to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

My input:

```
>>> bayer
array([[103],
       [ 98],
       [114],
       [103]], dtype=uint16)
```

I use bayer.tostring(), and I get:

```
 >>> bayer.tostring()
b'g\x00b\x00r\x00g\x00'
```

I want to convert bayer into 'gbrg'.  How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to convert to `uint8` and then use `tobytes()`:

```
>>> bayer.astype(dtype=np.uint8).tobytes()
b'gbrg'
```

Another alternative:

```
>>> bytes(bayer.ravel().tolist())
b'gbrg'
```

Or even:

```
>>> bayer.tobytes()[::2]
b'gbrg'
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a freshman, sorry to bother you again. I still have a probelm. It seems that 'gbrg' is different from b'gbrg'. How can I get the 'gbrg'?
```
>>> type(bytes(bayer.ravel().tolist()))
<class 'bytes'>
``` 
>>> type('gbrg')
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: I see. Use the bytes(bayer.ravel().tolist()).decode('UTF-8').  Thank you very much!

Comment: @xlsx yes, one is a bytes object the other is a string object. You need to `.decode()` the bytes object.